# Zeta function associated with a function $f$

Tags: cv.complex-variables, special-functions, riemann-zeta-function, zeta-functions, bernoulli-numbers

Let the function $f(t) = \cos(at)$, where ($0 < a < 1$). Let us define
$$\zeta(z, f) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(z)} \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{t^{z-1}\cos(at)}{e^t-1}\, dt.
$$
Is there a general formula that gives the values of $\zeta(2n, f)$ in terms of $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$, $a$, and the Bernoulli numbers?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I just want to know if there is a known formula for this integral. I think now that there is no. Thanks.